# command-line export data to php

Tags: python

I need to open an STL file with Blender, run a script that finds it's dimensions and send them to a php page. All of this should essentially be done through command line or a python script.

So far I've been using cmd with this command:

```
blender -b C:\blenderTesting\test.blend -o C:\blenderTesting\ -P C:\blenderTesting\test.py
```

blender -b C:\blenderTesting\test.blend opens the file in blender

-o C:\blenderTesting\ sets the folder for the file to be saved to when finished

-P C:\blenderTesting\test.py runs the python script that finds the dimensions of the object

When I use the above command cmd returns, Error executing Python script from command-line: C:\blenderTesting\test.py (at line 231).

This is the end of the python script

```
def write(filename):
    outputFile = open(filename, "w")
    outputFile.write(String);
    outputFile.close()
```

This is line 231 of test.py

```
Blender.Window.FileSelector(write, "Export")
```

I'm assuming the problem is that since I'm running this script via Blender background mode it can't open the export window in Blender. I don't want to do this anyway, since I want the script to automatically save the data in a php file. So is there a way to change the ending (line 231) of the python script to automatically save the data without using the export window?

If not, could I accomplish this another way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Uhm, could be I don´t get your problem, but calling write directly in your script doesn´t work for you?

Comment: if I open blender with the GUI and manually run the script that finds the data, and manually save it then it works fine.

Comment: Calling your write(filename) should also work in background mode. What errors do you get when trying this?

Comment: This is nice but I need to make it automatic, so I run it through the command-line. The problem is with the "Blender.Window.FileSelector(write, "Export")" line. I think this is because blender can't open the Blender.Window.FileSelector since it's being run in the command-line.

Comment: I know you want to do this automatically. Instead of calling Blender.Window.FileSelector.. just call write.

Comment: okay, I tried "write(C:\blenderTesting\test.php);"

Comment: but it came up with an error pointing to the : in (C:\blenderTesting\test.php)

Comment: filename should be enclosed in ""

Comment: ah just added parenthesis, write("C:\blenderTesting\test.php"); but know its returning invalid mode ('w') or filename on the line "outputFile = open(filename, "w")"

Comment: try "c:\\blenderTesting\\test.php" or "c:/blenderTesting/test.php"

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could run Blender through PHP, pass arguments (see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-give-command-line-arguments-to-blender-python-script)) and let Blender print JSON-encoded data wrapped by some text markers. Extract and parse the JSON-data with PHP and use it.

Example implementation:

https://github.com/CoDEmanX/blend_stats

Note that `Blender.Window.FileSelector(...)` is only valid in Blender 2.4x, API is completely different in 2.5x / 2.6x.