# Creating a Whole Cermaic Pot from Potsherds - Archaeology

Tags: modeling

I am an archaeology student tasked with creating a complete pot from just a few potsherds (broken pieces of pottery). I am new to Blender but was told that this program could help me. Is there any way to use my .stl file of one half of a ceramic pot and create the other half?

Comment: see this [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/open-stl-file-with-blender) and for creating the other half create the whole pot than use a boolean modifier to cut it again

Comment: Import it from blender then you can use a mirror modifier.