# Print all commands in the Info view?

Tags: scripting, command-line

The *Info* view doesn't show every command (scripts) which I actioned.
Example open new file, reload file, import, export...

How to show them?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) It would help us better understand what you want if you could add an example of a command which doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-give-command-line-arguments-to-blender-python-script ?

Comment: Sample in Maya, they show open file "file -f", import file "file -import", blender not show it http://i.imgur.com/7VT70ly.gif

Comment: Note that the commands shown in the info window are python calls.

Answer (score 5):

While the info window can be helpful, the list of commands it shows is not a complete list, some operators are intentionally filtered out because they don't relate to editing your data (panning the view for example or scrolling the text window).

One example is renaming an object, changing the name in the 3Dview properties sidebar or object properties shows in the info window but renaming in the outliner doesn't show.

With opening/reloading blend files, the info window is cleared after opening a blend file, so the open command would be cleared out. If you refer to opening text files in python, any task using basic python functions isn't going to show in the info window, a call to a bpy based function would need to be made for blender to echo it into the info window.

EDIT:
You can see most if not all of the missing actions by setting

```
bpy.app.debug_wm = True
```

Note that this will give a lot of extra entries, including zooming, typing in the console, scrolling up and down....

Comment: In short: there is no way to record actions (macros), also see http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/info_api_reference.html#operators

Comment: Actually `bpy.app.debug_wm = True` adds most if not all of the missing actions.

Comment: Definitely not all - e.g. doesn't show changing of properties.

Comment: Custom data is not exposed at all. Operators which require it may still show up in the info area, but can't be executed again with the command shown. Window Manager operators will lack the proper context and can't be repeated either.

Comment: I imported a glTF file and got nothing in the Info window, sadly. :-(

Comment: @GaryO the info window documents steps performed in blender. If you are looking for possible error information you need to look in the [console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/command_line/introduction.html).

Comment: @sambler Not looking for errors: I'd like to do some imports programmatically so I was hoping to see the python line it used to do the import.

Comment: @GaryO The line to use would be [`bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="/path/to/infile.gltf", import_pack_images=True, import_shading='NORMALS')`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf).