# Using argparse in script yeilds memory error

Tags: python, scripting

I want to get blender to work with argparse.
I found the following [implementation in blender here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/background_job.py) and tried to sum it down to this:

```python
import argparse
import sys
argv = sys.argv
if "--" not in argv:
    argv = [] # as if no args are passed
else:
    argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"
usage_text = "Run blender in background mode with this script: blender --background --python " + __file__ + " -- [options]"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=usage_text)
args = parser.parse_args(argv) # In this example we wont use the args
```

However when executed named as `argparse_blender.py` like this:

```
blender -b -P argparse_blender.py --  -h
```

I get as the last line:

```
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 216
```

Is there a way to fix this?
If not, is it serious? I care about memory leaks.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, so I use `try` and `except` to fix this problem in python 3.3 in blender 2.69.

#### Solution

```py
try:
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    do_something(args)
except SystemExit as e:
    print(repr(e))
# END OF FILE
```

#### Results

When we run blender like this:

```
blender --background --python argparse_blender.py -- -h
```

(Or like this `blender --b --P argparse_blender.py -- -h`)

We get the desired output:

```
usage: blender [-h]

Run blender in background mode with this script: blender --background --python argparse_blender.py -- [options]

optional arguments:                                                                                                                                
    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
SystemExit(0,)

found bundled python: [...]/blender/2.69/python

Blender quit
```

#### Suggestion

I would write the whole `argparse_blender.py` like this:

```py
import do_something
import argparse
import sys

argv = sys.argv
if "--" not in argv:
    argv = []
else:
   argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]

## set the prog name to match real usage
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description = 'Run blender in background mode',
    prog = "blender -b -P "+__file__+" --",
)
try:
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    do_something(args)
except SystemExit as e:
    print(repr(e))
# END OF FILE
```

Because it gives nicer output:

```
usage: blender -b -P argparse_blender.py -- [-h]

Run blender in background mode

optional arguments:                                                                                                                                
    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
SystemExit(0,)

found bundled python: [...]/blender/2.69/python

Blender quit
```