# bpy.context.space_data.text throwing error from command line

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I'm new to Blender and Python, but have programming experience.

I'm writing a script that iterates through all the .stl files in the current directory (current being where the script is), does a few things, then exports them as .fbx files.

When running it from the Scripting screen in Blender, it works great, but I want to run it from the command line.

When I do that it hits an error on this line that grabs the directory where the script resides:

```
workDir = os.path.dirname(bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath)
```

The error is:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Why does this work via the GUI and not the command line? Is there a different command I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: When you run from the text editor, the context.space_data.type is 'TEXT_EDITOR'  ie it is the context space.  When you run from CL the context space is None, hence your error.  What about something like `bpy.path.abspath(bpy.data.texts['Text'].filepath)`  However prob better  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script?rq=1 and pass the path via a command line argument.

Comment: bpy.path.abspath(bpy.data.texts['Text'].filepath) gives me the error: "KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Text" not found'"  Passing it as a command line arg may be what I do, but I'd hoped to be able to use the script from the command line or the gui.

Comment: "Text" needs to be the name of your text block.  Passing the path via the command line would be a better solution AFAIC than having the script in same folder as stl files and also having script opened in blender text editor.

Answer (score -1):

In the text editor window the [filepath] refers to file location where you save the script.
In the console window there is no such structure.

```
import bpy
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.today())
print(bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath)
print(bpy.data.filepath)
```

The above was executed in the Script window.  You can compare the results.

Comment: bpy.data.filepath gives me no output either in the GUI or via command line.

Comment: The file needs to be saved to have a `bpy.data.filepath`