# Workflow for batch rendering in the same scene with different cameras

Tags: rendering

I have a scene with 500 frames of a person walking. I want to render out several different viewpoints of this scene.

In the past, what I used to do is to create a new scene with everything linked except the camera, then I would use Blender command line to render all scenes. (Each scene has different start-end frame to match the length of the camera movement)

However, this cause me huge problem when I want to change some render settings as it could not be changed together to all scenes. (I set the size wrong once, then I set the noise handling wrong, then I set the FPS wrong, etc.)

Instead I have thought of a workflow with multiple cameras on only one scene. Currently I found [this way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75699/is-it-possible-to-assign-an-active-camera-through-command-line-rendering/75700) of setting the render camera via command line.

What's missing is I have to manually remember the frame range of each camera and use it in the command line.

My idea is to embed custom properties to the camera that specify start and end frame, then the command line maybe can gather all cameras in the scene and render them all regarding to this custom property. But I don't know how to do this. Or perhaps are there any better ways?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, never mind. I would rather use the old approach with Python script to change all the render settings like this

```
import bpy

def RenderAllScenes():
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        bpy.ops.render.render(scene = scene.name, animation=True)

def CommonSetup():
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
        scene.render.resolution_y = 1080 
        scene.render.tile_x = 256
        scene.render.tile_y = 256
    return

def Setup(resolutionPercentage):
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        CommonSetup()
        scene.render.resolution_percentage = resolutionPercentage
```

In Blender's interactive console I can then `import renderSettings.py` then `renderSettings.Setup(50)`, etc.