# How to output multiple images from Blender's compositor with Python?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I know how to render one image via Python and get an output with Blender's compositor.

What if I need it to render 100 images for me with numerical names e.g: `img_1`, `img_2`, `img_3` etc.?

Give me please an example of a working script via Ubuntu terminal and Python sys.argv?

Can I for example setup compositor nodes, and then simply render scene and get composited render as a result render?

Python code for rendering 1 image:

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]

current_frame_path = argv[0]
print(argv)
ob = bpy.context.active_object
scene_rd = bpy.context.scene.render

scene_rd.filepath = current_frame_path
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Shell script for rendering `n` images

```
#!/bin/bash

imgs_cnt=n

output_frame_path='RenderedImages/img'


for (( i=1; i<=imgs_cnt; i++ )); do
  echo "Rendering frame ${i}/${imgs_cnt}..."

  (
    cd /path/to/model/
blender --background Model.blend --python Render.py-- "${output_img_path}/img_${i}.png"
  )

  echo "Image ${i}/${imgs_cnt} has been rendered"
done
```

Here's an example for what I'm trying to do:

This is an automatically generated scene with plants, and I render it via executing `shell` script in terminal. It use 3 python scripts for blender. 1st script is for generating the scene, it places objects on the scene with different location and rotation settings and check if objects are intersected (to avoid clipping). 2nd script is for rendering scene. 3rd script isn't yet ready but it will be generating a mask for generated scene via cryptomatte.
As a final result I want blender to output me 2 images into 2 different  directories. 1st for the original images and 2nd for mask annotations.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. I suggest showing the relevant code you have for rendering 1 image. The last sentence comes across a little demanding and probably won't go down well with other users.

Comment: @RayMairlot here you go

Comment: No extra args needed here `blender -b -f ${i} -o "${output_img_path}/img_###.png"` When useing `--` make sure it is clearly separated by spaces. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script  Would be a lot quicker to copy images from one render than to render each.

Comment: @batFINGER I use args because I render an original image, then a grayscale mask for it, and output them to different directories. My question is how to do the same, but when using compositor? I need an original scene render and cryptomatte image outputs

Comment: @batFINGER Can I for example setup a compositor nodes, and then simply render scene and get compositorED render as a result render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add File Output nodes to the compositor to get multiple files saved from any point of your compositing without the need for any Python:

[image]

You can also use Python to add more nodes:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree


for every_node in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(every_node)

RenderLayers_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')   
RenderLayers_node.location = 0,0

comp_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeComposite')   
comp_node.location = 400,0

links = tree.links
link = links.new(RenderLayers_node.outputs[0], comp_node.inputs[0])

for i in range(0,100):
    output_node = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeOutputFile')
    output_node.name = "Output node number "+str(i+1)
    output_node.location = (400,(-140-i*110)) 
    link = links.new(RenderLayers_node.outputs[0], output_node.inputs[0])
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNode.html) for more info.

Comment: That's now gonna work. What if I need to render 1000 images? I need to script it anyway

Comment: Fix typo: NOT* gonna work

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did not read the question carefully enough. See the update.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, appreciated your time. I updated the question with more detailed info of what I'm trying to achieve. Your answer kinda answers the question "How to render multiple images via compositor?" but that's not in the way I meant it

Comment: You might not be using Cryptomatte the way it is intended to be used if you are outputting the colourful image. Generally you should not see it ever. You should save Cryptomatte masks using EXR format with the rendered image or as separate greyscale masks using Cryptomatte nodes to generate them. https://www.exr-io.com/ might also be of interest...

Comment: Oh, no, wait, you have to see the image, but only for choosing what masks to generate :), anyway, it would defeat the purpose of Crytomatte if it was used for masks. You would have serious problems with the edges of the masks.

Comment: I need a colorful mask to convert pixel coords of each object on the scene to json format. As for my question, I'll figure it out from here, thanks for the tips. It would be ideal if I could output original scene in 1 dir, grayscale in 2nd dit, and colorful mask in 3rd dir.

Comment: Yeh, blender viewer and .exr file output have color differences

Comment: It should be fairly straight forward to set the output directories, just change the parameters of the output nodes. In my example that could be something like `output_node.base_path = "C:\\Render\\SomeDirectory\\"` I will not attempt to provide the full solution because I might not know the full context, I think it will be easier for you to know what exactly you need.

Comment: If you simply set path to output file node, it will overwrite image after each render, cause you can't iterate names via nodes