# Is there a way to output two videos from rendering - one with compositing and one without?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a scene with a fluid simulation and I want to know if the result is better with or without the *Vector Blur* node.

Is there a way to render a video where Blender first renders the image and exports it to a file and then adds the compositing nodes and exports the image to a different file?

This way you will get two video's at the end, one with compositing and one without.

This would save a lot of render time because you only have to render it once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I batch render multiple blendfiles consecutively?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74750/how-can-i-batch-render-multiple-blendfiles-consecutively)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.
Use a file output node in the compositor.

[image]

[How to output multiple images from Blender's compositor with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167202/how-to-output-multiple-images-from-blenders-compositor-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to do directly to a video format, but assuming you're following the practice of rendering out the video to individual frames before encoding them as a video you can create multiple image sequences.
In the Compositing workspace, add in a File Output node which takes in the raw output of the render layers node. Then, use another File Output node which takes in the processed output. For each File Output node you can set the output directory and all the format details you would normally specify from the output properties panel. Unfortunately, the file output node only supports image formats and no video formats hence the need to render out the animation as image sequence.