# Render a .blend file in command line

Tags: python, rendering

I have a `.blend` file with some pre-configured lighting, camera,... The script in the file loads an external `.stl` file and render in that condition and do a simple `bpy.ops.render.render()`, then save the rendered image.

Now I want to automate this task. I know that I can write a `.py` file and put some blender logic into it, then run from command line (with blender compiled as a module), but how about a `.blend` file? I want to pass the path to a `.stl` via `sys.argv`.

An alternative method is to write a new script and set the lighting, camera angle,... in the script, however, I don't have that much knowledge to do so, as the `.blend` file was prepared by someone else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass command line arguments to a Blender Python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script)

Comment: No. The script is embedded in the `.blend` file. It's simple, however, there're some configured things beside the script that I don't know.