# How to pass command line arguments through Blender without IndexError thrown?

Tags: python, scripting, error, command-line

I am trying to execute my command with two arguments in terminal:

```
blender -b Scripting_Testing.blend -P background_job.py -- 1 2
```

I have used:

```
import sys

try:
    index = sys.argv.index("--") + 1
except ValueError:
    index = len(sys.argv)
sys.argv = sys.argv[index:]
....
....
foot_position = sys.argv[1]
angle_movement = sys.argv[2]
```

(Used from [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script))

I get:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the parameters before "--" (+ 1 makes it inclusive) have been skipped here. The second line overrides the sys.argv to hold only items that go after "--", which is an array of length 2 containing [1, 2].

```
index = sys.argv.index("--") + 1
sys.argv = sys.argv[index:]
```

Array indices start from 0. You are trying to access a third parameter here

```
angle_movement = sys.argv[2]
```

This causes the out of index exception.
Should be

```
foot_position = sys.argv[0]
angle_movement = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!